# Displaying an 8x8 Grid in Windows 8 / WPF / Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to display an 8x8 Grid in Windows 8 metro app. To do this:

1. I created a `Grid`, and added 8 row definitions and 8 column definitions.
2. I then add a `Rectangle` with a black border to each of the grid cells.
3. Then in the `MeasureOverride` method, I check the `availableSize`. Since my grid needs to be square (aspect ratio = 1.0), I compute the minimum of `availableSize.Width, availableSize.Height` and return a new Size equal to `(minimum, minimum)`.

However this does not work. The resulting grid's size is equal to `availableSize`, and not the size I return from my `MeasureOverride` method. If I modify the `MeaureOverride`, so that I set `Height` of `RowDefinition`s to `minimum`, and `Width` of `ColumnDefinition`s to `minimum`, then it works. But I saw some videos and they say you should not be explicitly setting `Height` & `Width` properties of anything.

So, is there a **better** way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to interact with those cells in any way, but if you just want to draw a grid, here is a quick control to do it. It will fill the space of the parent control.

```
public class GridShape : Control
{
    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(GridShape), new PropertyMetadata(8));

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(int), typeof(GridShape), new PropertyMetadata(8));

    public Brush Stroke
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Stroke", typeof(Brush), typeof(GridShape), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(GridShape), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness);

        double heightSpan = ActualHeight / Rows;
        double widthSpan = ActualWidth / Columns;

        for (double y = 0; y <= ActualHeight; y += heightSpan)
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, y), new Point(ActualWidth, y));

        for (double x = 0; x <= ActualWidth; x += widthSpan)
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, 0), new Point(x, ActualHeight));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a custom Grid control to handle the width, height

```
    public class SquareGrid : Grid
{
    public SquareGrid()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as FrameworkElement;
        if (parent == null) return;

        ResizeToSquare(parent);
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as FrameworkElement;
        if (parent == null) return;

        parent.SizeChanged += ParentOnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void ParentOnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs sizeChangedEventArgs)
    {
        FrameworkElement parent = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (parent == null) return;

        ResizeToSquare(parent);
    }

    private void ResizeToSquare(FrameworkElement parent)
    {
        var min = Math.Min(parent.ActualHeight, parent.ActualWidth);

        this.Width = min;
        this.Height = min;
    }
}
```

You could also build a Behavior for this that would do the same thing.